# Latest data sorted by latest date and test run

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if there is an easy way to sort a table view, so you only get every latest different test run, sorted by date.

I have a table with a date, engine (It's like a project name for a test, and it changes depending on tests), and the ID of every run.

```sql
SELECT 
    `testjob`.`id` AS `Testjobid`,
    `testjob`.`engine` AS `Engine`,
    `testjob`.`StartTime`
    FROM TestRun
    ORDER BY `testjob`.`StartTime` DESC
```

So after the SQL is run, this table will be shown:

[image: SQL Table]

But actually I only need this:

[image: Needed SQL]

**NOTE:** This table updates every day, and the engine names will also change over time, so I cant just type the three engine names and get the latest data that way. 
The only solution I can think of, would be making an SQL to get every engine name, and then make a loop to run through the table for every engine, but I hope there is a better way than this?

Comment: Can someone please point to where in Stack Overflow's help pages it suggests that this is an acceptable way to present a question? Failing that, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Most people here want _sample table data_ and expected result as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to use stackoverflow, i will remember that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select tr.*
from TestRun tr
where tr.StartTime = (select max(tr1.StartTime) from TestRun tr1 where tr1.engine = tr.engine);
```

In newer version, you can use `row_number()` :

```
select tr.*
from (select tr.*, row_number() over (partition by tr.engine order by tr.StartTime desc) as seq
      from TestRun tr
     ) tr
where tr.seq = 1;
```

If you have a ties with `starttime` then sub-query will need to modify with `limit 1`.

Comment: Thanks! the first example worked for me, didn't think about this!